# Is there a way to multiple metrics sort in victoriaMetrics

Tags: promql, victoriametrics

This is the payload I am sending to api endpoints, victoriametrics does not provide sorting based on metric values(like sql database sort by function). I there some method/feature of victoriametrics/promql to apply sorting?
***.

{
"entity_type":"office",
"sort_member_attribute":"cpu_usage_ppm",
"group_member_attributes": [
{
"attribute": "cpu_usage_ppm"
},
{
"attribute": "io_ppm"
},
{
"attribute":"storage_ppm"
}
]
}***

Answer (score 2):

Sorting by value is supported by functions [sort](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#sort) and [sort_desc](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#sort_desc). And sorting by labels value is supported by functions [sort_by_label](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#sort_by_label) and [sort_by_label_desc](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#sort_by_label_desc).